# Convergence of the difference of two random variables with the same limiting distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I stumbled upon this old exam question and cannot find a good solution. One is supposed to proof the statement if it is true or give a counterexample if it is false.

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be sequences of random variables and $Z$ be a random variable with non-degenerate distribution:

If $X_n \overset{d}{\to}  Z$ and $Y_n \overset{d}{\to}  Z$, then $X_n - Y_n \overset{p}{\to}  0$

My first attempt was the following:

$Y_n - X_n \overset{d}{\to} Z - Z \implies Y_n - X_n \overset{d}{\to} 0 \implies  Y_n - X_n \overset{p}{\to} 0 $

By the equivalence of convergence in probability and distribution for a constant. I am pretty sure this is incorrect.

Doing further research I stumbled across [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187009/is-slutskys-theorem-still-valid-when-two-sequences-both-converge-to-a-non-degen/187383#187383) and tried to use the example given in one of the answers as a counterexample for this problem.

Let $(X_0, Y_0)$ be Gaussian random vector with variance 1 and covariance $\rho$.
Define $X_n := X_0$ and  $Y_n := Y_0$ for $n \geq 1$. Given that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are on their own standard normal they converge in distribution to any standard normal RV: $X_n, Y_n \overset{d}{\to} Z \sim N(0,1)$.

Given that we know the covariance matrix of the random vector $Y_n + X_n$ is Gaussian with variance $ 2+2\rho$. However, $Z+Z = 2Z$ would also be Gaussian, but with variance $2$ and hence $Y_n + X_n$ cannot converge in distrubtion to $2Z$. Applying the example to $Y_n - X_n$. Using the variance formula we get $V(Y_n - X_n) = 2\rho$. Contrary, $Z_n - Z_n$ would have a variance of $0$ and thus be degenerate.

Is this example applicable to this question or am I missing something? Is this a good counter example that shows that the first step in my attempt is incorret?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: To me this is a very good counter example. As a complement, if you don't know about it check Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: Your first step is incorrect. It would hold if we knew that $(X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow{d}(Z,Z)$ jointly. Then the application of the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) would imply your assertion.

Comment: Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be independent and all have the same distribution as $Z$   The assertion is obviously false.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple counterexample, involving discrete random variables.

Toss a fair coin once. Let $X$ be the number of heads observed, and let $Y$ be the number of tails observed. For each $n$ define $X_n:=X$ and $Y_n:=Y$.  Then everybody has the same distribution, hence $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ converge in distribution to the same non-degenerate limit. What can you say about $X_n-Y_n$?